# How to implement cancel button in JConfirmDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a java swing application. This application contains a mainframe window.

When the user clicks the close (X button on top right of window), my application pops up a `JOPtionPane` Confirm dialog with yes, no and cancel operations. Clicking on `yes` saves some files and closes the application, `No` closes the application without saving the results. This all has been implemented and working fine.

Now i need to implement `cancel` operation which should typically do something like close the `ConfirmDialog` and keep the application still open (contrary to this yes and no option closes the application)". I need to implement the idea of "application should not be closed upon clicking the cancel button". For any existing example one can consider the closing of excel sheet (after you edit the excel and try closing without saving).

Comment: What have you tried?  Handling "cancel" should be as simple as closing the dialog and doing nothing else.  Please show your code and indicate where you're having trouble.

Comment: Firstly, make sure that the frame's `defaultCloseOperation` is set to `JFrame#DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, this now gives complete control over to you. You will need to monitor the `windowClosing` event and take appropriate action, which, from the sounds of it, you've already done

Comment: JConfirmDialog?  Please take more care to copy/paste these things, rather than waste our bandwidth with a random clutch of letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the default close operation for the frame to do nothing:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE )
```

Your `windowClosing` event handler can then literally just return if the user clicks `cancel` and the program will continue as if nothing has happened.

If the user clicks `yes` or `no` then your code will need to programmatically close the frame.

Comment: i am using the following statements in my code 1) getFrame().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); 2) under window closing event i have added int option_choosen = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainPanel, "Do you want to save the results of simulation before exiting the application?", "Save Results ?", 1) 3) Under Yes and No options i have added getFrame().dispose() 4) I have added under cancel option nothing